# Multiple taxonomy And acf filter group by

Tags: wp-query, loop, advanced-custom-fields, groupby

I have a widget that must display my custom post type. I don't display title or content, but just the values of 3 custom fields (acf) : start date, end date and city.

Here is my loop. I grab all the custom post that have the selected taxonomies (category and level). It's working.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'formation',
    'posts_per_page'    => $instance['number_events'],
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'categories-formations',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $tax_id,
        ),
         array(
            'taxonomy' => 'niveau-formations',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    =>  $niveau_id,
        ),
    ),

);
$upcoming_events = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $title ) {
    echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
}
// vars
?>
<ul class="event_entries">
    <?php  
    while( $upcoming_events->have_posts() ): $upcoming_events->the_post();
        $event_start_date = get_field( 'date_de_debut');
        $event_end_date = get_field('date_de_fin' );
        $city = get_field('ville'); 
        $posts = $upcoming_events->posts;
        echo '<h3>' . $city . '</h3>';
        echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li>Du' . $event_start_date . ' au ' . $event_end_date . '</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    endwhile; ?>
    <?php
    wp_reset_query();
    echo $after_widget;
}
```

In frontend, I have my list with the city name as h3 and the corresponding start and end date in a ul li group.

```
Paris

    Du13/07/2020 au 24/07/2020

Paris

    Du22/06/2020 au 26/06/2020

Orléans

    Du18/05/2020 au 22/05/2020
```

What I want to have is to group by city name, in order to have this: (all dates corresponding to a particular city grouped together)

```
Paris

    Du13/07/2020 au 24/07/2020

    Du22/06/2020 au 26/06/2020

Orléans

    Du18/05/2020 au 22/05/2020
```

Please can anyone help me because i'm on this since two days, trying multiple queries and loop. I don't know how to achieve this. I would like to understand the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, in your tax queries (`tax_query`), you should use `'field' => 'term_id'` and not `'field' => 'id'` — i.e. use `term_id` and not `id`. But the default value/field is `term_id` (term ID), though.

So you can achieve the grouped display like so, and you'd use the code in place of those lines starting from the `<ul class="event_entries">` up to that `wp_reset_query();` — you don't need to reset the global/main query because you're just making a *secondary* query which doesn't touch the global `$wp_query` variable:

```php
<?php
// First, group the posts by the city.
$groups = array();
foreach ( $upcoming_events->posts as $i => $p ) {
    $city = get_field( 'ville', $p->ID );

    if ( ! isset( $groups[ $city ] ) ) {
        $groups[ $city ] = array();
    }
    $groups[ $city ][] =& $upcoming_events->posts[ $i ];
}

// Optional, sort the city names.
ksort( $groups, SORT_FLAG_CASE );

// Then display the posts.
if ( ! empty( $groups ) ) {
    echo '<ul class="event_entries">';
    foreach ( $groups as $city => $posts ) {
        if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
            // Display city name.
            echo '<h3>' . $city . '</h3>';

            // Display posts in that city.
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
                $event_start_date = get_field( 'date_de_debut', $post->ID );
                $event_end_date   = get_field( 'date_de_fin', $post->ID );

                echo '<li>Du' . $event_start_date . ' au ' . $event_end_date . '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>'; // close .event_entries
}
```

Note that I'm assuming all the posts always have a *valid city*.

Also, the above technique doesn't alter the original posts in the `$upcoming_events` object, and if you called `setup_postdata()` in your code, you should also call `wp_reset_postdata()` at the end of your code/function.

### UPDATE: In response to your comment.

Sorry, I can't give a full tutorial or detailed guide on [The Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/), but check that linked article and you'd at least understand *what is, and how to use or work with* The Loop.

However, what I can tell you from the above code, are:

1. When you do `$upcoming_events = new WP_Query()`, the `$upcoming_events` variable becomes an instance of the `WP_Query` class and therefore, the variable will inherit/contain all the (public) properties (e.g. `$upcoming_events->posts`) and methods/functions (e.g. `$upcoming_events->query()`) of the class. And you can find out about those properties and methods by checking the official reference [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/).
2. "*I also don't understand what is `$upcoming_events->posts as $i => $p`'..what are `$i` and `$p`??*" - `$i` is the index of the current item in the `$upcoming_events->posts` which is being looped through, whereas `$p` is the value of that current item (i.e. `$upcoming_events->posts[ $i ]`) which is a [`WP_Post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/) instance — but if you're having trouble understanding that "current item", then you need to check the PHP [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) on `foreach`, or you can ask or search for "What is `foreach` in PHP?" on Stack Overflow..
3. "*I also don't understand `$groups[ $city ][] =& $upcoming_events->posts[ $i ];`*" - well, that is just an alternative to `$groups[ $city ][] = $upcoming_events->posts[ $i ];` (copying; note the `=` versus `=&`). And it's called "assigning by *reference*" which basically helps improve performance in that we don't need to copy the post objects to `$groups` and simply *reference* to them in the original `$upcoming_events->posts`.

   See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768343/reference-assignment-operator-in-php) and/or [this article](https://www.elated.com/php-references/) for more details.

   But basically, think of references like *shortcuts* in your computer; e.g. an icon on the desktop that points to a file, e.g. a text file. So `$my_var =& $file;` is like making a shortcut to that text file, whereas `$my_var = $file;` (once again, note the `=` vs `=&`) is like you copied the file to your desktop.
4. "*I don't understand what is inside the `$posts` variable*" - if you mean that `foreach ( $groups as $city => $posts )`, then that `$posts` is an array of post object *references*, so `$posts[0]` for example, is a reference to `$upcoming_events->posts[0]` which is a post object. I.e. They both point to the *exact same* `WP_Post` instance (see point #2 above).

So I hope those 4 points help you, but for more information about *PHP-specific things* like `foreach`/loop and references, please ask on Stack Overflow or search on Google, etc. :)

Comment: First of all, i'm really greatful to you, you saved me hours or days of headache ! I really appreciate your help and I just had to copy your code and it's working perfectly...Thank you very very much!!!

Comment: I still have question regarding your code. I didn't know that I could use a '$upcoming_events = new WP_Query($args);' and then a foreach loop, instead of the traditionnal 'while( $upcoming_events->have_posts() ): $upcoming_events->the_post();'.. I also don't understand what is 'posts as $i => $p )'..what are $i and $p?? I also don't understand '$groups[ $city ][] =& $upcoming_events->posts[ $i ];' And finaly I don't understand what is inside the '$posts' variable..I'll look at this closer in order to understand. But you help me improve my skill. Thanks a lot. Gracie mille !!

Comment: So I have revised the answer, but you'll need to take time to check all the links, I mean *read* (and understand) the contents. We would not master a skill at a blink of an eye, right?.. However, please first accept the answer (i.e. mark it as correct) since I believe it already answered your original question. :) Happy coding & all the best!

Comment: Thank you so much Sally !!